# Google Chrome - How to force immersive mode using JavaScript and/or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'd like to force immersive mode in Google Chrome.

I found a solution for the opposite action, which checks to see if immersive mode is on and if so it turns it off, but I'd like to do the opposite of that.

```
(document.webkitIsFullScreen)(document.webkitCancelFullScreen();)
```

Any ideas?

And could someone provide a working example or a fiddle for this?

Comment: Just a pedantic nitpick but jQuery is JavaScript so JavaScript *or* jQuery makes no sense :p

Comment: [requestFullScreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)? [Fullscreen Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Comment: Well there may be a pure JavaScript solution so that's why I said JavaScript or Jquery. But ok, if they are the same then my bad.